# Converting HTML element to Int returning NaN Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, counter, nan, parseint

I am attempting to make a player health counter, however I am still getting NaN returned.. Help

**Here is my HTML**

```
<!--player 1 hp-->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
        <h2 class="text-center" id="play1HP">0</h2>
        <button onclick="healthCountUp1()">+1</button>
    </div>
```

**And my JavaScript**

```
function healthCountUp1(){
    var player1HP = parseInt(document.getElementById("play1HP").value);
    var add = player1HP + 1;
    document.getElementById("play1HP").innerHTML = player1HP;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`h2` element doesn't have `value` property, so `parseInt` will return `NaN`. You need to use `innerHTML` or `textContent` to get value. Also you need to update with variable `add`.

```js
function healthCountUp1() {
  var player1HP = parseInt(document.getElementById("play1HP").innerHTML);
  var add = player1HP + 1;
  document.getElementById("play1HP").innerHTML = add;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
  <h2 class="text-center" id="play1HP">0</h2>
  <button onclick="healthCountUp1()">+1</button>
</div>
```

---

```js
function healthCountUp1() {
  var player1HP = parseInt(document.getElementById("play1HP").textContent);
  var add = player1HP + 1;
  document.getElementById("play1HP").textContent = add;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
  <h2 class="text-center" id="play1HP">0</h2>
  <button onclick="healthCountUp1()">+1</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `innerHTML` and not `value`. This is happening because the `h2` element has not an attribute called `value`. So when you read the `value` of the `h2` you get `undefined` and when you pass `undefined` to the `parseInt` you get `NaN`.

```
 var player1HP = parseInt(document.getElementById("play1HP").innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

you had better make variable to store health value in:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
        <h2 class="text-center" id="play1HP">0</h2>
        <button onclick="healthCountUp1()">+1</button>
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
var health = 0;
function healthCountUp1(){
    health++;
    document.getElementById("play1HP").innerHTML = health;
}
```